# Looking for a mailing list system with click tracking capability 

Tags: url, email, email-address

we are looking for a mail system with the ability to know it a client has visited the link.

Our idea is to prepare a mail for a certain group of customers, on that mail we will include a url to our proposal/video/whatsoever . We would like to acknowledge if the customer has clicked the link.

Is that possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much all the major hosted options can do this. Take your pick(these all point at documentation):
[MailChimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-track-clicks-and-opens/)
[AWeber](http://www.aweber.com/faq/questions/323/What+is+Click+Tracking%3F)
[Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/email-marketing/email-tracking-reporting/index.jsp)
Campaign Monitor just does it automatically for all links, instead providing instructions on [turning it off](http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=83).

I also know that the self-installed [PHPList](http://docs.phplist.com/MessageTracking) can do it.

Comment: Plus 1 for MailChimp, I was going to throw that into the pot if no one else had.